# Find the values of $x$, where $x \in \Bbb C$, for which $x^4-1 =0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Find the values of $x$, where $x \in \Bbb C$, for which

$$x^4-1 =0$$

I can see that $x^4-1 = (x^2-1)(x^2+1)=0$

So one set of roots can be taken from $$x^2-1=0$$$$ \Rightarrow x=\pm1$$

However, for $$x^2+1=0 $$$$\Rightarrow x=\sqrt{-1}$$$$\Rightarrow x=i$$

So from where does the last given answer of $-i$ come? I thought $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $i^3=-i$, so can you please explain in what way does $-i$ work as a solution?

Comment: $(-i)^2 = (-1)^2i^2 = 1\cdot (-1) = -1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quadratic equation over $\mathbb{C}$ has always *two* solutions. So in particular, $x^2-1=0$ 
has two solutions, $x=1$ and $x=-1$, as has $x^2+1=0$, with $x=i$ and $x=-i$. The solutions of $x^4-1=0$ are called the $4$-th roots of unity, and they lie on the circle in the complex plane.

Here is the computation again: $(x+i)(x-i)=x^2-i^2=x^2+1$.

Comment: "A quadratic equation over a field has always two solutions" ??

Comment: Oops, I wanted to say, a polynomial of degree $n$ over a field has at most $n$ roots.

Comment: what about $x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Jonathan He's saying **at most**!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: no, it was my fault. I have edited my answer. So thanks to Jonathan.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am talking about your comment, not your answer.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff ah, I misread the comment, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2=a^2\implies x=\pm a$

If $a=i, a^2=-1, x=\pm i$

i.e.,

$x^2+1=0\implies x^2=-1=i^2\implies x=\pm i$

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Euler's formula:
$$
e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)
$$
where $x = \frac{2\pi k}{n}$ and $0\leq k < n$.

So in your case $n = 4$ and $k = 0, 1, 2, 3$.

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\exp\left(\frac{i\pi k}{2}\right) &= 1 &&\quad\text{when } k = 0\\
&= i &&\quad\text{when } k = 1\\
&= -1 &&\quad\text{when } k = 2\\
&= -i &&\quad\text{when } k = 3
\end{alignat*}

Comment: *You can always use Euler's formula* to solve the problem posed **to** the OP, but not to answer the question posed **by the OP**...

Answer (score 1):

The bug in your work is:

> $x^2+1=0 \implies x=\sqrt{-1}$.

A counterexample to this is $x=-\sqrt{-1}$ also satisfies $x^2+1=0$.  (The implication actually goes the other way: $x=\sqrt{-1} \implies x^2+1=0$.)

The claim

> $x^2-1=0 \implies x=\pm 1$

is implied by the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).  Specifically, the corresponding polynomial has exactly $2$ (not necessarily distinct) roots.  Having found $2$ roots, we can stop looking.

---

Again, the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra implies that there are exactly $4$ (not necessarily distinct) roots of a degree $4$ polynomial; in this case $x^4-4$.  This means that as soon as we've found $4$ roots, we can stop searching, as there are no more roots.

Now, for any polynomial $f$ with complex coefficients, if $z$ is a root, then the complex conjugate of $z$ is also a root; Wikipedia has a page on this: [Complex Conjugate Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem).  In this case, $i$ is a root, and the theorem implies that $-i$ must also be a root.